# Proper way to insert variables into a MySQL insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, quotes

I seem to always have issues getting variables into my MySQL querys.

Is there a good tutorial or could someone show me the proper way of getting variables into the statement?

The main issue I am having is with the different types of quotes (' or ").

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO classes (
                        class_name, 
                        user_id, 
                        professor_name, 
                        class_start, 
                        class_end,
                        school_period) 
        VALUES('" . $className 
                . "','" . $userID 
                . "','" . $classProfessor 
                . "','" . $classStart 
                . "','" . $classEnd 
                . "','" . $classPeriod . ");)" 
                . '"';
```

Comment: try this

`$sql = "INSERT INTO classes (class_name, user_id, professor_name, class_start, class_end, school_period) VALUES('".$className."','". $userID ."','" . $classProfessor . "','" . $classStart . "','" . $classEnd ."','" . $classPeriod . "')";`

Comment: You will need to escape your data. How to do this depends on the database library you are using.

Comment: @kumar_v you're not escaping it though

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just fixed error in query. As you said, it's all depending on the library he used. thanks

Comment: What you should be doing is using PDO or mysqli with placeholders, which (almost) entirely removes any need to "embed" variables in your query

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use prepared statements: http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements 
as that is the best way to execute sql

Comment: Is vital to mention the variables need to be escaped, and is much better to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @AstDerek you are right, I just simplified query at code level. as **its not mentioned which db extension is used.**

Comment: From the context you can understand OP's code does not escape any variable, otherwise he wouldn't have problems with quotes, or the overall idea of the insertion

Comment: @AstDerek its mentioned in question "The main issue I am having is with the different types of quotes (' or "). " so i posted the possible simplification sql string (not query). regarding your view for PDO & mysqli, its always the best idea to use them rather than the old mysql extension as its also deprecated

Comment: its mentioned in question **Question: "The main issue I am having is with the different types of quotes (' or "). "**

Answer (score 4):

Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not try to make a correct SQL string yourself.
This is how you get [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

[How to use placeholders](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-execute.php)